# How to bind clicks on new data loaded with AJAX? -- JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of links with a 'Show more' Ajax request which loads more:

```
<a href="#" class="item">abc</a>
<a href="#" class="item">abc</a>
<a href="#" class="item">abc</a>
```

I have a binding function this that does something:

```
$('.item').click(function(e) {
  // some stuff
});
```

Problem is that **when I load more of these links with Ajax, clicking them doesn't go to this function!**

How could I "re-bind" all links to make the new ones work as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to bind handler if you use jQuery < 1.7

```
$('.item').live('click', function(e) {
  // some stuff
});

$('body')delegate('.item', 'click', function(){

});
```

if you use jQuery > 1.7 you should use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) but you must attach the event handler to an element to which you delegate the event handling and that element must be present in the DOM when you attach the handler.
So if you have a container for your links you should use that or otherwise you could use the body element.

```
<div id='container'>
<a href="#" class="item">abc</a>
<a href="#" class="item">abc</a>
<a href="#" class="item">abc</a>
</div>

$("#container").on("click",".item",  function(event){

});
```

or if there is no container(it has a greater overhead)

```
$("body").on("click",".item",  function(event){

});
```

Comment: Is that depreciated in > 1.7 ?

Comment: Yes it's deprecated, but i think you can still use it. They discourage it. If you jQuery > 1.7 use on();

Answer (score 0):

You can use `on()` and this will fire on newly created objects :

```
$('body').on('click', '.item' function(e) {
  // some stuff
});
```

the first bit - `$('body')` should be a parent item of `.item` that is in the DOM at the time this function is run.